# In AWS IoT Core rule action or AWS Timestream database table how can we specify/configure measures?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, amazon-timestream

Following is the data in my message.

```
{
  "time_epoch": 1604489437,
  "temperature": 100,
  "device_id": "TempSensor1"
}
```

I have an IoT core rule that takes this msg and has an action to send it to the Timestream db table.

In the IoT core rule - I have configured device_id to be the dimension and time_epoch to be the timestamp. Screenshot below:

[image]

**Problem:** When the msg reaches the Timestream db table, the device_id is correctly showing as dimension. The time_epoch is correctly showing under time column. **However all 3 - device_id, temperature and time_epoch are getting shown as measures**. Screenshot below:

[image]

I imagined that - since I have specified in the IoT core rule action that device_id is the dimension and time_epoch is the timestamp, then AWS Timestream should have been smart enough to not include both of these as the measure.

How can I instruct timestream db to not consider device_id and time_epoch as measures; and only consider temperature as the measure? I tried editing the table  settings but there I could not find any option to specify/configure the measures.

Comment: Same question here. I've consulted this docs from Iot core
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/timestream-rule-action.html

It seems this is the default behavior of ingesting data to timestream.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM /your/topic
```

What you want to do is:

```
SELECT temperature FROM /your/topic
```

You will have to edit your dimensions to now use builtin functions instead of your SQL query results. Essentially, use `${clientId()}` for `device_id` and `${timestamp()}` for `time`. See documentation for a list of available [substitution templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/timestream-rule-action.html).

You should then see the table you expect to see.

The reason you are seeing the spurious measures currently is because, as [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/timestream-rule-action.html) state, Timestream converts each key of the JSON into its own measurement record.

Comment: That's not a solution if you need to get that data from the message